# How to Stop Error '91':object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm new to VBA so apologies if this is a really simple fix.

The following code keeps returning Excel Error '91': object variable or with block variable not set.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Intersect(Target, Range("$B$7")) = Worksheets("Team Amendment Tables").Range("$C$7") Then
 Application.Run "TargetUpdate1"

End If

End Sub
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?
Context: Drop Down List in Sheet 7 to trigger Macro: TargetUpdate1 Once without loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Intersect` will return `Nothing` if any cell other than B7 is changed, so test for that first:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$B$7")) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("$B$7").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$C$7").Value Then
            Application.Run "TargetUpdate1"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Absolute Legend. Thanks for your help!